# How to ping pingomatic.com with XML-RPC from a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rss, xml-rpc, ping

I want to automate sending pings to rpc.pingomatic.com but I can't find anywhere which documents the fields to send in the RPC document.

I'm not worried about a fancy RPC generator. I'm happy just to #{...} the link into a static string. I just need to know what to insert it into.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind, found this link: http://www.weblogs.com/api.html#5

Comment: Isn't there some kind of standard? or does every ping url have its own payload?